# How to align text/controls in datatable column?

Tags: css, xpages

I'm trying to align checkBox in datatable column (h=center, v=middle)

```
<xp:dataTable id="dataTableListView1" rows="30" style="width:100%" ...
    <xp:column id="column1" style="width:25px;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
        <xp:checkBox id="checkBoxSelect">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" ...
            .....
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:checkBox>
    </xp:column>
    ...
```

but the checkBox still shown in wrong place (see attached picture)

[image]

So how do I put it into center of the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following code to align checkbox in a datable

```
<div class="checkbox" style="margin: 0px 6px; height: 12px;display:inline;"><input id="view:_id1:_id2:callback1:viewPanel1:0:viewColumn12:_colcbox" type="checkbox" name="view:_id1:_id2:callback1:viewPanel1:0:viewColumn12:_colcbox" value="5898E"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Type F12 in your browser, and modify the style settings for the checkbox.  Or click right on the checkbox, then Inspect. Try with margin: 0 0 6px 6px